# Easily showing and hiding UI options for different releases of a standalone Java Application

Tags: design, development-process

I have a very simple standalone java application that allows users to tick which messages they want to transfer and then click go, essentially.

We now need to provide different users with a different set of messages on the UI.

e.g:
company 1 can only tick messages A,B,C and the rest aren't visible to them
company 2 can only tick messages B,D,E and the rest aren't visible to them
company 3 can tick any of A,B,C,D,E

The UI is loosely-coupled from the business logic , in that each "Message" is processed by the same code behind but with different parameters passed in. So the UI is just starting one thread per message, the same object type but with different parameters per thread, depending on what was ticked.

I am trying to understand if there's any way of getting Eclipse or Ant or something to generate the UI based on a config file per company, rather than having to maintain multiple UI code instances in our codebase?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you want to do more then simply grey out the disabled options:

Generate the GUI dynamically.

It's easy to get used to doing GUI's statically using the provided drag and drop tools but you can do GUI's completely in code. You just need to learn how. It's not by playing with Eclipse or Ant. It's good old Java code. Using Java the layout can be changed and components can be added dynamically.

Here's a fairly exhaustive [swing example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons).

This is hardly a Java only thing. My senor project was in .NET C#. It was a peer to peer universal board game simulator that let you play chess, tic-tac-toe, candy land, whatever. All you needed were pictures that became the board or pieces. We loaded those pictures into GUI components dynamically and let the user manipulate them.

The trick was figuring where and how to create the components with code. It isn't some magical setting you turn on. You just write code.

Comment: Thanks, I am writing the GUI using code, but still - you'd have to have a GUI class for each of the customers; depending on the messages they wanted; unless there's a better way of doing it. So generating the GUI dynamically per customer - yes, but how is that "generate" information best stored?

Comment: You could do a class for each KIND of customer. Or you could just do one class that lets you control which messages are tickable with data.